# Upload Images on Google Cloud SQL via PHP AppEngine App

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Can anyone help me draw out the code/ steps for uploading an image onto cloud SQL via the App engine? I take the snap from my Android app which calls the PHP app on the APP Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you upload to CloudSQL? You should be uploading to Cloud Storage.

Is [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#uploading_to_google_cloud_storage) not clear enough?